# Why do I get CannotStartContainerError when trying to start my ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, ecs-taskdefinition

I have a FastAPI application with the below Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

Everything runs correctly in Localhost and I can get the project of port 8888. I now want to deploy this project on AWS so I've created a repository on ECR service and pushed my images on this repository. I've then created a cluster & added a task.

The container of the defined task has a hard memory default limit of 128 MiB, uses an image stored in ECR and has correct port mappings.

When I want to run this task on the defined cluster, the status is set to `STOPPED` after adding and I get the below error:

> CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: container init was OOM-killed (memory limit too low?): unknown

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Bump up your memory limit from 128 to around 300 and then try again. If that fails, try 500. Does that work?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It solved the problem, thanks. You can share this comment as an answer

Comment: Glad to hear that - enjoy using AWS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your task (container) is being stopped because it is trying to use more memory than it is allowed.**

The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_memory) highlights this behaviour:

> If your container attempts to exceed the memory specified here, the container is killed.

The main hints here are the mention of *OOM* (out of memory) & *the memory limit too low?* question in the error message.

Increase your hard memory limit from 128MiB to around 300-500MiB, which is the ECS recommended memory range for web applications.

Once it just 'works', fine-tune the memory parameter according to your container needs.